# SonataMedia upload doesn't work on Amazon S3

Tags: symfony, amazon-s3, sonata-admin

I installed *SonataMediaBundle* and it works fine when I want to upload my files ***locally***.

But i would like upload my files on ***Amazon S3***. So :

- i updated my config file
- i added the bundle "*amazonwebservices / aws-sdk-for-php*" in my composer file.

But it doesn't work and i don't understand why ... is it there is any other action to do ?

Thank's a lot for your answers, i need help ... (I searched all morning before coming to ask this question)

My *config.yml* file :

```
sonata_media:
default_context: default
db_driver: doctrine_orm
contexts:
    default:
        providers:
            - sonata.media.provider.image
        formats:
            small: { width: 100 , quality: 70}
            big:   { width: 500 , quality: 70}
    Video:
      providers:
          - sonata.media.provider.image
          - sonata.media.provider.file
      formats:
          small: { width: 150 , quality: 95}
          big:   { height: 500 , quality: 90}
cdn:
    server:
        path: http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com

filesystem:
    s3:
        bucket: mybucket
        accessKey: myaccesskey
        secretKey: mysecretkey
        create: true
```

Comment: Can you detail `it doesn't work`?

Comment: thank's to your answer. I have no details ... The file is uploaded on local but this is no present on my bucket (amazon S3). My log files are also empty. I also look at the permissions on my bucket and everything is ok.

Comment: @guizme555 You got the answer ?